# Split string by " " in VB.NET

Tags: vb.net, split

Let’s say that this is my string:

```
1 2 3
```

I want to split the string by " " (space) and display every time part of my string.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

This will do what you need:

```
Dim str As String = "1 2 3"
Dim strarr() As String
strarr = str.Split(" "c)
For Each s As String In strarr
    MessageBox.Show(s)
Next
```

Comment: +1 Good answer.  MsgBox, however, is a throw-back to VB6.  The better method to use in .NET is MessageBox.Show.