# vb.net I want to break the words in my string

Tags: vb.net

My string is `myname mynickname`.

I want to get 2 word in my string `myname` and `mynickname`.

How to do in "vb.net"

Comment: Take a look at `String.Split`.

Comment: pls answer full coding to do it

Comment: possible duplicate of [VB.NET Split string by " "](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11118896/vb-net-split-string-by)

Comment: @ชม้อยศรีมีดีที่แวตา please atleast search before _ask a question_

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use the `String.Split` method:

```
Sub Sample()
    Dim theStringIWantToSplit As String = "myname mynickname"

    '' if there is a possiblility of multiple spaces between the words and you want to ignore them
    Dim sa() As String = theStringIWantToSplit.Split(" ".ToCharArray, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries)

    '' otherwise it is much simpler
    Dim sa1() As String = theStringIWantToSplit.Split(" "c)
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

```
dim xstr as string="myname mynickname"

dim xMyname as string=xstr.Split(" ", 
options:=StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries)(0)
dim Name as string=xstr.Split(" ", 
options:=StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries)(1)
```